# How to move a VS 2010 UML diagram to another project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

Does anyone know of a way to move a UML diagram from one Visual Studio 2010 project to another? I have two modeling projects that I'm trying to consolidate, but I'm not having much luck. It looks like only the XMI *import* functionality is included in Visual Studio 2010 Feature Pack 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Davester, you'll find a similar question that was answered on the VS Visualization & Modeling Tools forum:

[How can we import an existing *.usecasediagram file?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/vsarch/thread/dc300e9d-e59d-43ab-b5db-1bd1e386c0b2)

Basically, you have to copy over all the elements from the diagram in the source project over to a diagram in the destination project. The diagram files themselves belong to their parent modeling project and must be opened from that project.